# link MS Exchange and PHP with ExchangeWebServices?

Tags: php, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I'm currently studying computer science and in my work experience my work tutor proposed me to send requests for appointments via a site in PHP (realised by me) to my **tutor Microsoft  EXCHANGE agenda's.**
Unfortunately I don't know how to do this.... 
I have good knowledges in PHP, HTML and CSS but I'm totaly lost speaking Microsoft Exchange because  until my work tutor ask me this project, i didnt really know Microsoft Project.

my code (file : test.php):

```
<?php

function __autoload($ExchangeWebServices)
{
// Start from the base path and determine the location from the class name,
$base_path = 'C:/wamp/www/new-ews2/php-ews';
$include_file = $base_path . '/' . str_replace('_', '/',             $ExchangeWebServices) . '.php';

return (file_exists($include_file) ? require_once $include_file : false);
} 

$server='test.fr';
$username='test@test.fr';
$password='testtest';

$ews = new ExchangeWebServices($server, $username, $password);

$request = new EWSType_FindItemType();
$request->Traversal = EWSType_ItemQueryTraversalType::SHALLOW;

$request->ItemShape = new EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType();
$request->ItemShape->BaseShape = EWSType_DefaultShapeNamesType::DEFAULT_PROPERTIES;

$request->CalendarView = new EWSType_CalendarViewType();
$request->CalendarView->StartDate = date('c', strtotime('2015-06-20 -00'));
$request->CalendarView->EndDate = date('c', strtotime('2015-06-22 -00'));

$request->ParentFolderIds = new EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId = new EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType();
$request->ParentFolderIds->DistinguishedFolderId->Id = EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdNameType::CALENDAR;

var_dump($request); 

?>
```

When i go in my google chrome and set: `localhost/new-ews/php-ews/test.php`

result of the page :

```
object(EWSType_FindItemType)[2]
public 'CalendarView' => 
object(EWSType_CalendarViewType)[4]
  public 'EndDate' => string '2015-06-22T02:00:00+02:00' (length=25)
  public 'MaxEntriesReturned' => null
  public 'StartDate' => string '2015-06-20T02:00:00+02:00' (length=25)
public 'ContactsView' => null
public 'DistinguishedGroupBy' => null
public 'FractionalPageItemView' => null
public 'GroupBy' => null
public 'IndexedPageItemView' => null
public 'ItemShape' => 
object(EWSType_ItemResponseShapeType)[3]
  public 'AdditionalProperties' => null
  public 'BaseShape' => string 'Default' (length=7)
  public 'BodyType' => null
  public 'ConvertHtmlCodePageToUTF8' => null
  public 'FilterHtmlContent' => null
  public 'IncludeMimeContent' => null
public 'ParentFolderIds' => 
object(EWSType_NonEmptyArrayOfBaseFolderIdsType)[5]
  public 'DistinguishedFolderId' => 
    object(EWSType_DistinguishedFolderIdType)[6]
      public 'ChangeKey' => null
      public 'Id' => string 'calendar' (length=8)
      public 'Mailbox' => null
  public 'FolderId' => null
public 'QueryString' => null
public 'Restriction' => null
public 'SortOrder' => null
public 'Traversal' => string 'Shallow' (length=7)
```

I don't know how to test this code now? Do i ask my tutor the server / username / password now? or is my code good? Do i change anything? thanks

**edit 2** : On which line can i add this code please? :/

Comment: blimey what level work experience is this?!

Comment: madness.. your w/e tutor needs a wakeup call.  and happy birthday for tomorrow

Comment: why? :x is it too hard for my lvl? :/
Thanks bro'!

Answer (score 0):

There are many APIs for accessing EWS via PHP:

- [jamesiarmes/php-ews](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews)
- [more sources](https://curah.microsoft.com/56807/ews-client-libraries)

They will get you started.

**edit:**

After having your code - you must 
 1. include all files you need separately
 2. add a custom auto loader

Both is described in the readme document [here](https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews).
For solving the above error, you will have to include the file `ExchangeWebServices.php` at least.

**edit 2:**
You do not really query the EWS. You build the query - but do not execute the code. Of course you will need account data for querying.

```
$response = $ews->FindItem($request);
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more details. The relevant code parts you already have, and the results / error messages you get.